# Android Alarmmanager and notifications

Tags: android, android-intent, alarm

I have a task that I don't really know how to solve and hope that you can help me.

I have a Alarmmanager with daily alarms set up at a certain time and this alarm triggers local notifications. This is working fine so far.

The problem is that I want to have daily alarms where the time changes slightly.

Example:

Monday: Send notification at 14:00
Tuesday: Send notification at 14:05
Wednesday: Send notificaton at 14:10

I don't want to have different pending intents for every day, I rather want to change the pending intent and fire time.

Is this achievable?

Comment: I assume time difference is fixed,you can achieve this.First time you need to set time for 14:00 Tuesday,when broadcast receiver receives this alarm set new alarm again with updated time i.e (24 hr +5min) and so on

Comment: Hi! Yes the difference is fixed. Yes very smart solution. Thank you very much.

Comment: Please upvote my comment if it helped you